# Error with getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)

Tags: android, baseadapter

I use `getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` inside a class which is extended to `BaseAdapter`. As I guess the reason for this error is because I do not extend the class to `Activity`. Can I get out of this error by implementing the class to `Activity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I get out of this error by implementing the class to Activity

Yes, you can send Activity context using class constructor in which you are extending BaseAdapter.do it as:

```
private class YourBaseAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
 LayoutInflater vi;
public YourBaseAdapterClass(Context context) {

 this.context = context;
 vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
....
```

and pass context from Activity as:

```
YourBaseAdapterClass adapterobj=new YourBaseAdapterClass(Your_Activity_Name.this);
```